# showing the equation is true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Am from writing my class test and I have failed to answer this question. None of my friends could help me after the test was over.the question reads:

> If $P$ is the length of the perpendicular from the origin to the line which intercepts the axis at points $A$ and $B$, then show that $$\frac{1}{P^2}=\frac{1}{A^2}+\frac{1}{B^2}$$

Someone to help me do this.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

From area written two different ways, we get:

$$P\cdot C = A \cdot B$$

From Pythagoras:

$$ C^2 = A^2 + B^2.$$

($C$ is the length between the two points.)

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Let $Q$ be the point of intersection of the lines $P$ and $AB$. Then, $\triangle AOQ$, $\triangle BOQ$, and $\triangle OAB$ are all similar.

Comment: I suppose that assumption suggests that A=B

Comment: No, of course not. It's a general observation for all triangles. Two triangles are similar if they share two angles. In this case, a right angle is shared, plus the angle at $A$ or $B$.

Comment: @NGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA It is even a rather easy theorem: in a straight angle triangle ($\;\Delta OAB\;$) , the height to the hypotenuse divides the triangle in two subtriangles which are each similar to the whole triangle.

Comment: Let me try to do what you are suggesting